# Required Help in Hiding Table Rows - dc.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, dc.js

I'm using `dc.js` to plot chart and show data tables.

Everything runs quite good. And for the table i've created a `dimension` and also a `group`. Passing the group variable to dynatable records.

Problem is when I do some selection in the chart. The data table value are of course getting changed. But the there are few records which are supposed to hidden instead they come with `0` value.

I wanted to hide those rows.

Below are the functions I'm using.

**Table Dimension :**
`var tableDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.label; })`

**Table Group:** `var tableGroup = tableDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.count; })`

**Dyna Table:**

```
var dynatable = $('.data-table').dynatable({
        features: {
            pushState: false
        },
        dataset: {
            records: tableGroup.top(Infinity),
            perPageDefault: 10,
            perPageOptions: [10, 20, 100, 500, 1000]
        }
    }).data('dynatable');
```

**Refresh the table on chart selection :**

```
function RefreshTable() {
        dc.events.trigger(function () {
            dynatable.settings.dataset.originalRecords = tableGroup.top(Infinity);
            dynatable.process();
        });

        $('.data-table tr').each(function() {
            if ($(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text() < 1) {
                $(this).addClass('zero-value');
            }
        })
    };
```

I've written `jquery` codes to assign a class for the rows with zero-value. And it gets assigns only for the first 10 records as I've given the `perPageDefault: 10`. But I want to it run for the entire table records.

Some one please help me in hiding those rows with values 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before assigning the records in the dynaTable initialization and RefreshTable, you can copy the data and remove records that have value 0.

Dynatable is acting on the records that you pass it, so you can change that data in any way you see fit.

Comment: How can i target each rows in the `group` created. I'm unable to use `forEach` function. Error as `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'forEach' `.

Comment: var records = tableGroup.top(Infinity); will retrieve an array containing all the group data.

Comment: Sorry. I still get records with 0 value. Used this `records.forEach(function(d) { if( d.value == 0 ) { delete d} })`.

Comment: tableGroup.top(Infinity) returns a new array containing the records in the group.  Use your favorite process for altering an javascript array and then pass that array (don't call tableGroup.top(Infinity) again) to dynatable.